# Applying border on a div is increasing its height significantly

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple page that contains just a paragraph inside a division as below

```
<html>
  <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <title>Floating</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="block.css">
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="parent">
           <p>Floating </p>
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css is also pretty simple

```
#parent {
   border: 1px solid #f00;
   background-color: #ff9;
   max-width:1000px;
}

p {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

The question is with the border applied the height for the parent div is 82px as seen in the chrome dev tools. But as soon as I disable the border the height reduces to 50px. I simply dont understand that why the application of just a 1px border causing this much height difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a feeling this might be due to collapsing vertical margins. When vertical margins of the parent and child are not separated by a border, they will collapse.

Comment: Its interesting. I've made a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/ojbxpsLk/

Comment: Using CSS reset or normalize seems to be solving the problem. Also, try adding * { margin:0; } and the behaviour with/without border becomes consistent, so it looks like it has something to do with Chrome's box model interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

This behavious is part of the [CSS2 Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) and is called 'collapsing margins'. In various situations, a parent/child relation included, the margins of two elements are combined into the largest of the two. This is true if there is no other content or borders inbetween.

The border of the parent prevents their margins to collapse. Once you remove the border, the margins collapse into one margin of (in my case) 16px (the default margin of the `p` element), and that margin is applied to the outer element (the parent), which is why the background-color of the parent is no longer visible. The content area of the parent has collapsed with it.

So if you want a border, but don't want that yellowish area around the paragraph, you can either set the margin of the `p` to 0, or you can add the border to the `p` rather than the parent. I think, knowing the cause, you can figure out which solution suits you best. :-)

And if you think my explanation is somewhat brief and W3's explanation is too technical, make sure to read the [explanation by SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/) which is quite elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the default margin from the `<p>` element.  **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ctfngggj/)**

```
p {
   margin: 0;
   color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: That works, but it still doesn't explain why it happens this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have used `<p>` tag. Look at the following demo with `div` instead of `p`:

http://jsbin.com/ciwomayuri/1/

To avoid this attach margin property to your `p` as this example:

http://jsbin.com/hifadijera/1/

As [JRulle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643482/jrulle) said, there is a default margin value with each browser for the `p` tag like being default font family and font colors.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of style so called "user agent stylesheet". 
By default tag `<p>` has margin-top and margin-bottom = 1em. And if you remove border attribute from #parent, tag `<p>` wont change its default attributes. 
You can check it by hovering it in code inspector. Since parent div has no border, so there is no object to wich from `<p>` browser has to fill a color #ff9. 
Anyway total height of `<p>` (including margins) is permanent. 
Default attributes have lowest priority. So if you define margin-top and margin-bottom of `<p>`, it will be under your full control :)